# Actionscript 3: How do I have a button that allows a group of buttons to rotate 90 degrees at a time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript

I'm very new to the actionscript in the Adobe Flash. I have a cluster of buttons as a navibar and I want to rotate it 90 degrees at a time after each press of a button.  I've done some research and I've found out that rotating a button could be impossible.  Of course, I can try using the Movie Clip instead of the button, but I would like to keep it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You just say `buttonName.rotation = 90` What's impossible about that?

Or if you want to rotate the cluster (as in "...rotate it..." in your question?), instead of the individual buttons, put all the buttons inside of a MovieClip and rotate the MovieClip.